# With Monthname and Year search date in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, date

This will be a little confusing to explain i think...

I have a form where you choose a month (mes), a year (ano) and a type of movement (movimento)

what i want to do is to create a search query that finds at the database (fluxo) all the repeated data from those 3 values that you choose on the form, my problem is that when i choose the 3 the SUM that i get is from all the types of movement i have (tipo) and i just want those that respect all the 3 field i´ve choosen before, i wanted to know if there is a possible way to join MONTHNAME and YEAR to search by database for a repeated date

here is my code:

```
$result5 = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(valor) AS value_sum FROM fluxo WHERE tipo = "'.$tipo.'" AND MONTNAME(data) = "'.$meses[$mes].'" AND YEAR(data) = "'.$ano.'" having count(tipo, data)>1  '); 
$row5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result5); 
$sum5 = $row5['value_sum']; 

$n=1; 

echo "<p>Os seus resultados:<p>";



echo "<table border=0>";
echo "<tr bgcolor='#CCFFCC'>";
echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>Tipo</td>";
echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>Movimento</td>";
echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>Valor</td>";
echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>Data</td>";
echo "</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result4)){ 
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>";
    echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>".$row['tipo']."</td>";
    echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>".$row['movimento']."</td>";
    echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>".$row['valor']."</td>";
    echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>".$row['data']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";

echo "<p> Valor errado, apenas a somar tudo: " .$sum5;

?>
```

i know this might sound a little confusing

Answer (score 0):

To search by a month/year I usually use something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` LIKE '".$year."-".sprintf("%02d",$month)."-%'";
```

I don't know if this is the best solution performance wise, but it works pretty well for what I use it for.